# MVC 4 app users sometimes get logged off when creating new item in production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 app and am using the default authentication provider.  I'm not using persistent cookies.

I don't have any problems in development but when hosted at HostGator, I SOMETIMES get logged off when I try to create a new item (HTTP POST).  When this happens, I end up at the log on page like I wasn't authenticated.

HostGator does NOT have the app on multiple web servers so I'm thinking I shouldn't have to worry about machinekey stuff.  Am I wrong?

When this happens, I just log in again and create the item again and it will succeed.  Once this happens, I can't recreate the issue.  I try reopening the browser and even different browsers but creating items will always work.  It only seems to happen again if I try much later.

Some additional info, the timeout is set to 2880 (the default for an MVC project), which I know is long but I can't see how it would be related.  Still, thought I'd mention it.

So I can't look at IIS logs or event viewer to get any idea what could be happening but I can add more logging to the app.  Can anyone provide ideas for what to check or what logging to add to diagnose?

Thanks

EDIT

I realized that I could get to the IIS logs so I compared the POST that succeeded and the one that failed and immediately noticed something.

When I first did the GET to load the Item/Create page/view, the cs-username was populated but when I did the POST to create the item, it was gone.  I can see that when I logged in again and was able to successfully create the item, that POST did have the cs-username populated.

Why would it disappear between the GET and the POST?  There was a 7 minute delay from the GET to the POST but I can see I logged on 1 minute before the GET so the session was only 8 minutes old when the post happened.  I've double checked that I don't have sessionstate explicitly configured so the default should be 20 minutes.  I feel like I'm onto something but not sure exactly what.

Comment: Dumb question: when you say "default authentication provider," do you mean MVC4's default (`SimpleMembership`) or the "classic" provider, the `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider`?

Comment: @TiesonT. I started with the MVC 4 VS template which uses AspNetSqlMembershipProvider in the AccountController implementation included in the template

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth adding Glimpse, although running that on deployed code is kinda risky. It would have the benefit, though, of letting you see what's actually happening on the server. I've never used HostGator, so I can't say for certain, but if they recycle app pools aggressively, that would invalid your login, and explain why the logoff seems to happen randomly.

Comment: Never used Glimpse.  I'll look into that and add some logging around application_shutdown as well to see if that is it.  I'd be surprised if app restarts were happening because then it could happen at any time, on GETs or POSTs, but it specifically only happens on the create item which is one of the few POST actions.

Comment: Glimpse was pretty cool but I couldn't run it on HostGator because it needs Full Trust and HostGator runs Medium Trust.

Comment: Do you use the `AntiForgeryToken`? I've had that force a login on posts at times, usually if I navigated backward and tried a new post with the "old" form data.

Comment: No, not using AntiForgeryToken but I did find a clue.  I updated the main question so some new info.  Thanks for the ideas so far.